# How to auto-complete the constructor parameters in PhpStorm?

Tags: macos, phpstorm

I used to be able to press <kbd>Option + Return</kbd> when my cursor was in the constructor signature, and it would automagically setup all my properties based on the signature. Like this http://g.recordit.co/zqwxu3hGQO.gif

At some point or during some upgrade - that stopped working. It's bugged me for weeks.

Does anyone know what that feature is called so that I can look in my preferences and give it a quick key again?

PhpStorm 2017.3.6, MacOS 10.13.5

Comment: Nothing has changed -- it's still there. 1) Check that you are still using correct shortcut to bring that menu (in other words: does it appear in other places?) 2) if it works -- Ensure that `PHP | Initialize fields` intention is enabled in Settings/Preferences.

Comment: Thanks @LasyOne.  "intention" was the word I needed to know.  I went into settings ... but it was on.  Somehow it fixed when I toggled it off/on.